# Using vuex state within vue-router resolver

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I am trying to add resolvers into my current project which uses Vuex and Vue Router.

Everything has been working perfectly so far other than when I try to access the state within the resolver which is defined `beforeEnter` on the route.

Here is my current setup:

```
{
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'dashboard',
    component: () => import('./views/Dashboard.vue'),
    beforeEnter: DashboardResolver
}
```

And this is the resolver:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import store from '../store/auth.module';

export default async (to, from, next) => {
    to.meta.user = await axios.get(`/users/${store.state.currentUser.id}`);

    next();
}
```

The crazy thing which I cannot understand is if I do `console.log(store.state);` then I get the state but if I do the following, on the same line `console.log(store.state.currentUser);` then it returns null which is the issue I am facing here.

Comment: where u write the console.log()

Comment: I am guessing if you log `store.state` followed by `debugger` you will find that state does not actually have data at that moment.

Comment: You are using Vuex modules - are you sure that it is `store.state.currentUser` and not `store.state.auth.currentUser` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV I tried both of them and neither of them actually seem to work

Comment: You can try with a Vuex getter instead. Or show us the contents of your `store.state`.

Comment: @IVOGELOV I have tried with a getter and it's still the same result. `store.state` if logged is exactly what I expect it to be `{ currentUser: {...} }` but if I log `store.state.currentUser` straight after that then I get null, although I can see the line previous it is null

Comment: Then probably there is a timing issue - try to change your `console.log(store.state.currentUser)` to `console.log(!!store.state.currentUser)` - or even better, `console.log(JSON.stringify(store.state.currentUser))`